# 403 Forbidden - Nginx, Docker & Windows

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm currently trying to setup a local dev machine with docker, using nginx. I recently switched from Virtualbox support to Hyper-v, and since then I get a 403 Forbbiden in Nginx.

I'm following this tutorial to set up things
http://tech.osteel.me/posts/2015/12/18/from-vagrant-to-docker-how-to-use-docker-for-local-web-development.html

My Nginx config is as follows

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And my docker-compose

```
nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - app

php:
    build: ./php/
    expose:
        - 9000
    links:
        - mysql
    volumes_from:
        - app

app:
    image: php:7.0-fpm
    volumes:
        - ~/docker:/var/www/html
        #also tried .:/var/www/html
        #and ./docker:/var/www/html
    command: "true"

mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes_from:
        - data
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: project
        MYSQL_USER: project
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: project

data:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/mysql
    command: "true"

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    links:
        - mysql
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
```

Docker folder is inside my C:/User/docker

What's the catchup here?
Thanks

Comment: What's in your NGINX logs? There should be an error log that is specific to the process, and an access log which writes out request/response errors. `/var/logs/nginx` are the common path for log files.

Comment: Apparently is configured as per .conf file `access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
` but when I ssh to docker-machine, i see that /var/log hasn't the nginx folder...

Comment: Are you logged in as the docker user?

Comment: @R0MANARMY I just do a `docker-machine ssh`. How can I verify that?

Comment: I meant on windows, but I'm not sure if volumes are the issue here, so probably OK to skip it for now.

Comment: @R0MANARMY Yes. I have full privilege and I'm set as Hyper-v admin as well. Probably the best way is to, as pointed out by Alan, to check on the logs. But I have no idea where they are...

Comment: Does the app need to connect to the database? That seems to be the only container without a `link`

Comment: It will need eventualy. But removing those containers doesn't change anything

Comment: Just reverted back to Virtualbox driver and everything works... So, definitely something with Hyper-v

Answer (score 0):

Verify that `index.html` or `index.php` exists in your `C:/User/docker` folder as if that doesn't exist, you will see 403 forbidden as by default you cannot browse the directory.

Then try the following in your docker-compose:

```
volumes:
    - /C/User/docker:/var/www/html
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

A stable dockerfile and image is available on the port of Docker's open source to Windows by WinDocks.   WinDocks runs on all editions of Windows 8, 10, Server 2012 and 2016.   The 1.04 release includes support for Tomcat, Jetty, Nginx, and Node.js.   Free Community edition is [Here](http://www.windocks.com/community-docker-windows)

*Disclosure: I am the Co-Founder of WinDocks*